# How to change color of a UIButton while pressed ONLY and cancel color change if released before x amount of seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm trying to make a button change color while being pressed for 3 seconds. Once timer reaches 3rd second the color change is permanent but if user releases button before time is up the button goes back to its original color. What I have so far is this: 
in `viewDidLoad`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(fireSomeMethod)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 3.0;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

in `fireSomeMethod` I have

```
- (void)someMethod {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.button
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                animations:^{
                    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    NSLog(@"animation finished");
                }];
}
```

This requires me to hold the button down for 3 seconds for the animation to fire and animation itself takes 2 seconds to complete. The desired behavior is that animation starts when longPress starts and I release button before 3 seconds everything goes back to the way it was. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of button event no need to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

Make 2 action for your button, one is for `Touch Down` and other is for `Touch Up Inside`

like this

```
// For `Touch Up Inside`
- (IBAction)btnReleased:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"time - %d",timeStarted);
}
// For `Touch Down`
- (IBAction)btnTouchedDown:(id)sender {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
    timeStarted = 0;
}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {\
    timeStarted++;
}
```

Create 2 variable `timer` of type `NSTimer` and `timeStarted` of type `int`. Fire the timer on `Touch Down` and invalidate it on `Touch Up Inside`, and in `Touch Up Inside` action method get the total time till your button is hold.As shown in the above code